# multicolumn not working with pgfplotstabletypeset and tabularx

Tags: tabularx, pgfplotstable, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to reproduce a table with multicolumns like this one:

[image: multiple columns table]

I understand that I should use multicolumn and multirow for producing the desire effect. This is the code I made:

```
\documentclass[
  english,
  a4paper,
  10pt,
  openany
]{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{titlesec} % customize title format
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry} % customize global margings
\usepackage{caption} % customize figure captions
\usepackage{graphicx}% include graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % customize header and footer
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % customize toc
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, tabularx, booktabs, multirow} % Generates table from .csv
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl} % use colors for tables
\usepackage{ifpdf} % customize PDF output
\ifpdf
\usepackage[pdftex,
  pagebackref=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  unicode
]{hyperref}
\fi



\begin{filecontents*}{matrix.csv}
  Max Current supply,\multicolumn{2}{l}{2A}
  \multirow{4}{*}{Enclosure},Material,Aluminium
  ,Dimensions, 300x200x87 mm
  ,Weight, 2.2 Kg
  ,External Protection, IP65
  Temperature Range,\multicolumn{2}{l}{-20$^\circ$C / 50$^\circ$C}
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableset{zerofill}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  reset styles,
  debug=true,
  string type,
  header=false,
  col sep=comma,
  row sep=\\,
  every first row/.style={
    before row={
      \vspace{0.2em} % first row space between rows
    }
  },
  column type=,
  begin table={
    \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
        >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}l@{\hskip 1.4em}
        >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X
        >{\columncolor[gray]{.95}}X
      }
  },
  end table={\end{tabularx}\endgroup},
  every nth row={1}{ before row={\vspace{0.2em}} }, % set space between rows
  every head row/.style={ output empty row },  % suppress printing head row (numbers)
]{matrix.csv}

\end{document}
```

Compile using the command:

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --synctex=1 --file-line-error" -use-make myfile.tex
```

No output is produced and the error message says that the number of columns don't match:

```
...PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger than the previously determined number of columns...
```

I know the problem is the use of multicolum because if I remove the multicolumn command (and add a new column at the end) it produces this output:

[image: multi row image]

Could somebody englight me why is multicolumn not working with pgfplotstabletypeset? and if there is a solution to use multicolumn or other alternative to produce a table like the example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the idea of the package is mostly _not_ to have tex markup in your csv file. It is probably possible to specify the column spans with suitable row specifications in the pgfplotstable setup, but do you need this at all, in your real example do you need to use a csv and then try to apply table markup to it, rather than just write the table directly (which is much easier)  If you have a large data file produced by some other software then the package is a useful way to typeset that by tex, but your csv already contains tex markup so is tex specific, so why not just make a latex tabular directly?

Comment: I like the idea of having the data and the representation apart. It is because I use pgfplotstable package. I understand that should not be latex commands should be in the "data" file, but I see no other way.

Comment: if you put `\multicolumn` in to your data file then you have more than anything not separated the data and presentation, then trying to separate the rest of the presentation aspects from the place that you are specifying `\multicolumn` vastly complicates the coding, for no clear benefit.

Comment: why are you using `-shell-escape` here (that should only be used with caution)

Comment: I am trying to not to put the **data** part (.csv) in the **representation** (.tex). If you have any solution, please answer the question.
Regarding the **-shell-escape** is just for executing the example, I don't think is going to make any difference, but thanks for the suggestion.